# Vuex: How to properly call action?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm having trouble understanding how to pass actions with payloads using Vuex. I know i need a mutation to change the state, and that its best practice to use an action to dispatch the mutation. Not sure how I call the action and pass in a parameter though. Whenever I try this I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isComplete' of undefined"

```js
// Store.js
const mutations = {
  completeTodo: function (state, todo) {
    console.log(todo)
    todo.isComplete = todo.isComplete || false
    state.toggleAll = false
  }
}

const actions = {
  completeTodo: ({commit}) => commit('completeTodo')
}

//Todo.vue

 methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    'completeTodo'
  ])
}
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="isCompleted" " v-on:change="completeTodo(todo)" class="todoCheck" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action should take a second argument which is the payload that you are passing in your component.

```
const actions = {
  completeTodo: ({commit}, todo) => commit('completeTodo', todo)
}
```

---

More details

Think of like this.

Component => Knows about the todo and a completeTodo function (which is the action provided by vuex mapActions).  It doesn't have to know about the store or any functions in order to get its job done.

mapActions => generates a 'smart' completeTodo function that takes care of the specific function in the store to call and the order of the arguments to correctly call it.